# как исправит ошибку PHP CORE WARNING – YII\BASE\ERROREXCEPTION

Tags: php, php7

когда слил сайт на хостинг выводит ошибку `PHP CORE WARNING – YII\BASE\ERROREXCEPTION`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
половина страниц выводится без ошибки. на локальноь сервере ошибок нет.

Comment: после авторизации ошибки не выводится

Comment: Доброе утро. Ошибка не имеет никакого отношения к yii2, а относится к библиотеке, которая установлена на Вашем компе.

Comment: А что надо делать. как исправить?

Comment: У Вас какая система?

Comment: win 7. на локальном сервере ошибок нет. это на хостинге ошибка выводится

Comment: вот адрес сайта   http://otzov.remobi.ru/kategorii/remont-noutbukov

Comment: раз ошибка выводится на хостинге, то и свяжитесь с тех. поддержкой хостинга. Пусть у них голова болит.

Comment: в панели управления сайтом поищите модуль morpher и включите его, после чего перезагрузите сервер